# Computing the Uniswap V3 pair price from Q64.96 number

Tags: solidity, blockchain, uniswap

I am trying to compute a Uniswap V3 pool token price in Solidity.

I can get the square root price of Q64.96 number as `uint160` (e.g., `1234217676608908277512433764` - value of DAI/ETH pool (price at that time around 1 ETH for 4090 DAI)).

This can be retrieved via `IUniswapV3PoolState.slot0()`

As the function docstring says: "sqrtPriceX96 The current price of the pool as a sqrt(token1/token0) Q64.96 value"

How can I convert this number to `uint256`?

The calculated price should suggest the value of 1 ETH for 4090 DAI

Is there any other way of getting the Uniswap V3 pair price?

The answer would preferably be in solidity, but other answers are also acceptable.

**Unsuccessful attempt**

I tried squaring the number `1234217676608908277512433764` and then shifting it by 96, but the result was `1.922666416729829e+25` which doesn't seem too be correct.

`(1234217676608908277512433764^2) >> 96 = 1.922666416729829e+25`

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsSFr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsSFr.png) Then what is the usage of Tick in here?

Answer (score 21):

The relationship between sqrtPriceX96 and price is metioned in the official doc:https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/guides/fetching-prices

```
    sqrtPriceX96 = sqrt(price) * 2 ** 96
    # divide both sides by 2 ** 96
    sqrtPriceX96 / (2 ** 96) = sqrt(price)
    # square both sides
    (sqrtPriceX96 / (2 ** 96)) ** 2 = price
    # expand the squared fraction
    (sqrtPriceX96 ** 2) / ((2 ** 96) ** 2)  = price
    # multiply the exponents in the denominator to get the final expression
    sqrtRatioX96 ** 2 / 2 ** 192 = price
```

Comment: Where did `sqrtRatioX96` at the bottom come from?

Comment: `sqrtRatioX96` and `sqrtPriceX96` are interchangeable terms according to the official docs linked in this answer

Comment: thanks for this, good mathematical breakdown

Comment: Just a note that ABOVE link is 404 now and needs to be replaced

Answer (score 17):

```
function getPrice(address tokenIn, address tokenOut)
    external
    view
    returns (uint256 price)
{
    IUniswapV3Pool pool = IUniswapV3Pool(factory.getPool(tokenIn, tokenOut, FEE);
    (uint160 sqrtPriceX96,,,,,,) =  pool.slot0();
    return uint(sqrtPriceX96).mul(uint(sqrtPriceX96)).mul(1e18) >> (96 * 2);
}
```

Returns spot price with 1e18 precision. Be careful to use spot price because it is a subject for a flash loan attacks. Either use TWAP price or check that price hasn't move much before using spot price.
Also, I haven't tested this code for precision loss and upper/lower boundaries. Because Uniswap v3 use Q64.96 notion for decimals but it doesn't seem that practical. The output of the function is a number with e18 precision. It depends which decimal lib you use in your project.

Comment: This does not seem to generalize well. How would this work on a pair like usdt/wbtc which is of decimals 8 and 6 respectively?

Answer (score 5):

TLDR: This is something that seems to work with every token (regardless of how many decimals it has) and it takes into consideration math overflow issues. Read explanation below:

```
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/libraries/FullMath.sol';

function sqrtPriceX96ToUint(uint160 sqrtPriceX96, uint8 decimalsToken0)
    internal
    pure
    returns (uint256)
{
    uint256 numerator1 = uint256(sqrtPriceX96) * uint256(sqrtPriceX96);
    uint256 numerator2 = 10**decimalsToken0;
    return FullMath.mulDiv(numerator1, numerator2, 1 << 192);
}
```

**Regarding decimals:** If you are calculating the price on a token with 18 decimal places, multiplying `sqrtPriceX96` by `1e18` before the division should work just fine, but it will break for tokens with other decimals (USDC anyone). In order to obtain the correct results you should pass `ERC20(token0).decimals()` to the above function.

**Regarding math overflow:** Depending on the price you convert the uint256 will overflow and you will end up with a wrong price. The safest way to do this is with the `MathFull.sol` library from Uniswap v3 which accounts for overflowing.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to calculate the price is by taking advantage of the relationship between `liquidity`, `sqrtPricex96` and token amounts.

```
import '@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/libraries/FixedPoint96.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/libraries/FullMath.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol';
import '@uniswap/v3-core/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Factory.sol';

function calculatePriceFromLiquidity(
  address token0,
  address token1,
  uint24 fee,
  address factory
) public view returns (uint256) {
  IUniswapV3Pool pool = IUniswapV3Pool(IUniswapV3Factory(factory).getPool(token0, token1, fee));
  (uint160 sqrtPriceX96, , , , , , ) = pool.slot0();

  uint256 amount0 = FullMath.mulDiv(pool.liquidity(), FixedPoint96.Q96, sqrtPriceX96);

  uint256 amount1 = FullMath.mulDiv(pool.liquidity(), sqrtPriceX96, FixedPoint96.Q96);

  return (amount1 * 10**ERC20(token0).decimals()) / amount0;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong/misleading, if the active liquidity in a pool is 0 then your function would attempt to divide by 0. Liquidity is irrelevant to calculating price, the only reason your function returns the correct price(provided liquidity != 0) is because your function can be reduced to the same formula as many of the other answers listed here:

(sqrtPriceX96 * sqrtPriceX96 * 1e18)/(2^96 * 2 ^ 96) = (sqrtPriceX96*sqrtPriceX96 * 1e18)/(2^192)

Answer (score 1):

We can adapt code from the actual Uniswap v3-periphery library function [OracleLibrary.getQuoteAtTick](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/v1.3.0/contracts/libraries/OracleLibrary.sol). Instead of having the function accept the `tick` and then convert the `tick` to `sqrtRatioX96` using `TickMath.getSqrtRatioAtTick(tick)`, we modify it to directly accept the `sqrtRatioX96` as shown below:

```
/**
 * @dev Calculates the amount of quote token received for a given amount of base token
 * based on the square root of the price ratio (sqrtRatioX96).
 *
 * @param sqrtRatioX96 The square root of the price ratio(in terms of token1/token0) between two tokens, encoded as a Q64.96 value.
 * @param baseAmount The amount of the base token for which the quote is to be calculated. Specify 1e18 for a price(quoteAmount) with 18 decimals of precision.
 * @param inverse Specifies the direction of the price quote. If true then baseAmount must be the amount of token1, if false then baseAmount must be the amount for token0
 *
 * @return quoteAmount The calculated amount of the quote token for the specified baseAmount
 */
function getQuoteFromSqrtRatioX96(
    uint160 sqrtRatioX96,
    uint128 baseAmount,
    bool inverse
) internal pure returns (uint256 quoteAmount) {
    // Calculate quoteAmount with better precision if it doesn't overflow when multiplied by itself
    if (sqrtRatioX96 <= type(uint128).max) {
        uint256 ratioX192 = uint256(sqrtRatioX96) * sqrtRatioX96;
        quoteAmount = !inverse
            ? FullMath.mulDiv(ratioX192, baseAmount, 1 << 192)
            : FullMath.mulDiv(1 << 192, baseAmount, ratioX192);
    } else {
        uint256 ratioX128 = FullMath.mulDiv(
            sqrtRatioX96,
            sqrtRatioX96,
            1 << 64
        );
        quoteAmount = !inverse
            ? FullMath.mulDiv(ratioX128, baseAmount, 1 << 128)
            : FullMath.mulDiv(1 << 128, baseAmount, ratioX128);
    }
}
```

To further simplify getting the price we can define the following function.

```
/**
 * @dev Returns the fixed-point price for a specified sqrtRatioX96, denoted in terms of token1/token0.
 * This function simplifies the process of obtaining the price from sqrtRatioX96 by using a standard
 * base amount (1e18) and setting the price as non-inverted (token1/token0).
 *
 * @param sqrtRatioX96 The square root of the price ratio between two tokens, encoded as a Q64.96 value.
 * 
 * @return priceU18 The calculated price in terms of token1/token0, with 18 decimal places of precision.
 */
function getPriceFromSqrtRatioX96(uint160 sqrtRatioX96) internal pure returns (uint256 priceU18) {
    // if we specified inverted = true, then we'd get the price in terms of token0/token1
    // whereas the UniswapV3Pool sqrtRatioX96 is in terms of token1/token0
    return getQuoteFromSqrtRatioX96(sqrtRatioX96, 1e18, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a rust lib that simply returns the price and abstracts the calculations away. Feel free to use it https://github.com/FredCoen/uniswap-utilities

Answer (score 0):

Had to write code for this exact purpose but with both decimal numbers variable, this did the trick for me:

```
 function getPrice(uint160 sqrtRatioX96, uint dec0, uint dec1)
    external
    pure
    returns (uint256 price)
{

uint256 dec = dec1<=dec0 ? (18-dec1)+dec0 :dec0;
uint256 numerator1 =uint256(sqrtRatioX96) *uint256(sqrtRatioX96);  
uint256 numerator2 =10**dec; 
price = FullMath.mulDiv(numerator1, numerator2, 1 << 192);
}
```