# How to convert price to sqrtPriceX96 in solidity?

Tags: solidity, uniswapv3

This [question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/98685/computing-the-uniswap-v3-pair-price-from-q64-96-number) asks how to convert sqrtPriceX96 to price in solidity, but I can't find information on doing the inverse.

How do you turn a price e.g. 55 ether into its sqrtPriceX96 with full precision?

Have tried

```
uint160 sqrtRatioX96 = 1827333235122231383957021222;
uint256 ratio = sqrtRatioX96.formatSqrtPriceX96ToPriceX96().formatX96ToX10_18();
uint256 sqrtRatioX96b = ratio.sqrt() << 96;
```

Which results in `1827333155895382849688627663268216832` (a different number than the original)